# Magento plugin help

Tags: html, phtml, head

First of all, i'm new to magento, i've read a few books and tried google before posting my problem.

Our company has a widget which we want to make available on the magento store, I have so far downloaded and attempted to create my own plugin to do this, but I feel I'm missing something due to the shire simplicity of this request.

The widget needs to add a javascript include into the head of the html document on every page once installed, it also needs to include a custom API key to be sent along with the include as well.

I have tried doing this programatically with:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addJs('path-to-file/file1.js');
```

This method didn't work and on further investigation using the addJS method won't allow external usage of javascript includes only js or js_skin which are both located locally.

I then turned my attention to using the layout files to add hooks into the reference "head"

```
 <reference name="head">
        <block type="js_widget/widget" name="js_widget" template="js_widget/widget/widget.phtml" />
    </reference>
```

This called a template file with the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript' id='widgetJS' src="//js.domain.com/widget.js?apikey=[API_KEY_HERE]"></script>
```

None of the above work and I have diasbled the cache to reflect changes instantly, could anyone aid on adding a javascript include to the head of the document with a custom api key varible, which I will need to build into the admin area once this section is completed in order to be changed for each install.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

if the script you want to add needs to be added to all pages and it's static (the api key doesn't change dynamically on the same website), then the easiest way to do it is to use the admin interface. Go to Configuration > Design and under *Miscellaneous Scripts* add the script.

if you need to change the api key for each request (or for each user, or similar), then you'll need to write some code. In your layout file, under the `<default>` handle (if you want it displayed on all pages), add the following:

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/template" name="widget_js" template="mypath/widget.phtml" />
</reference>
```

create the widget.phtml file under the mypath folder (you can change both to anything you like) and put the js code in there.

you'll need to populate the api key variable using php code, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick response, I am looking to create a plugin which any user can install, fill out their API key after installation and the javascript will be included in the .

I am new to plugin development, but need to make this pluggable so that all code is contained within my plugin's directory.

I have created a controller Widget.php which is located in, Test / Widget / Widget.php, I thought creating a few methods in this controller to get the API Key and using this in my XML layout file, pointing at this controller would include this in the Head and allow me to populate the API key within the phtml template file:

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="test_widget/widget" name="test_widget" template="test/widget/widget.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

This however hasn't been the case and the Javascript doesn't show up, the plugin needs to be installed and every site has a unique API key which is inserted by the user through their admin area.

Comment: Welcome to SE Steve. Please use the answers area for answers only. If you need to clarify something about your question you can always edit it. If you need additional info for one answer you can comment on it.